# Azure AD provisioning IS never sending request to the POST /Users/ endpoint when creating user

Tags: azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim, scim2

I am trying to implement the Azure AD Scim provisioning, I have successfully setup the /Users/ GET endpoint. But when starting the provisioning process, it just never sends the POST request to create the User. I have tested all of the /Users/ endpoints (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT) via postman and they work.
[image]
[image]

This is the response im sending in the first GET step:

```
        "id" => "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse",
        "totalResults" => 0,
        "itemsPerPage" => 10,
        "startIndex" => 1,
        "schemas" => ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"],
        "Resources" => []
```

I have yet to implement a response for the POST request as I am not receiving it, so I dont know what data I am gonna receive.

Also I cannot edit the settings now, everytime I click on save it just says this:[image]

EDIT-------
I have run the provisioning just now azure says that everything was set successfully, but the Create POST request never came!!!??? HOW??
[image]
Apache access.log is just showing GET requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in my router. The framework I was working with was changing the url route from `/scim/Users/` to `/scim/users/` which was causing the bug.

I dont know how the provisioning setup went through though. And even worse, why did it show me, that the provisioning was successful :D.

EDIT:
The start provisioning / stop provisioning is sometimes bugged. Where it will tell you that the cycle went through, but the requests never came.